# ListView with custom adapter and other view elements

Tags: android, android-layout

I am learning to use the [Hierarch Viewer tool](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html), but meanwhile any hint on why below layout is not rendering correctly is appreciated.

I am trying to render an "html" table view. The content (table body) is rendered correctly with a custom list adapter. This works. But, when I add a textView (text_test below) to use as header, the list is not rendered anymore. I could see the code flow through my adapter (populate view holder, etc), but on screen I only see the Title text, no listView. I used to use FrameLayout (as noted in the comment), but then switched to LinearLayout.

Thanks.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_view, container,
                false);
        ListView lv = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.my_list_view_one);
        // Tell the list view which view to display when the list is empty
        //lv.setEmptyView(getActivity().findViewById(R.id.my_list_view_empty));

        // Set up the adapter
        mCustomAdapter = new ListAdapterMyType(inflater, new ArrayList<MyType>());
        lv.setAdapter(mCustomAdapter);
        return  view;
    }
```

### my_list_view.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- The frame layout is here since we will be showing either
the empty view or the list view.  -->
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:text="@string/text_test"/>

        <ListView
                android:id="@+id/my_list_view_one"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

        <!-- Here is the view to show if the list is emtpy -->
        <TextView android:id="@+id/my_list_view_empty"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:text="@string/list_no_items"
                  android:visibility="gone"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But, when I add a textView (text_test below) to use as header, the list is not rendered anymore.

The TextView is set to `match_parent` in both the width and height, so it will fill the entire screen... To put a TextView above your ListView try:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/text_test"/>

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/my_list_view_one"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

    <!-- Here is the view to show if the list is emtpy -->
    <TextView android:id="@+id/my_list_view_empty"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:text="@string/list_no_items"
              android:visibility="gone"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I removed the outer LinearLayout, since it only had one child it did nothing. I also changed the remaining LinearLayout's orientation to `vertical` and set the header TextView height to `wrap_content`.

If you want your custom header to scroll with your ListView, use the [`addHeaderView()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29) method (*before* calling `setAdapter()`) instead of a separate TextView in your layout. This approach will also hide the header when the ListView is empty.

Comment: Thanks Sam. It indeed was an issue with filling up the layout, not only in the code above but even the cells of the list view. Appreciate your help. Cheers.

Comment: Also thanks for mentioning setHeaderView, which I never knew before.

Comment: btw, it is addHeaderView not set :-)